# Prevent other users from selecting another work item when using the Estimate extension for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-boards

We use the `ms-devlabs.estimate` extension for ADO, in our story pointing/backlog refinement sessions. The PO will set up an estimate session, with the tickets to be pointed, and then during the meeting we'll all jump onto the board.

The PO will choose a ticket from the list to estimate, we'll talk about the ticket, and then vote. Votes are revealed, we talk about the estimate we provided and then settle on a number or re-vote. All pretty straightforward.

The problem we have is that if somebody clicks another ticket in the list, we all get a refreshed screen with the newly selected ticket, and all the votes are lost on the ticket we were estimating.

Is there a way to lock the ticket list on the left-hand side, so only the PO/host can select a different ticket for the team?